# Замыкание границ

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, opencv, компьютерное-зрение

Есть ли какие-нибудь умные детекторы границ, которые делают замыкание? Для описания -- пример. Предположим, нашли границы тем же Кэнни или Собелем или ещё чем-нибудь. Возникает вопрос: границы рваные, как их замкнуть. Есть ли тулзы, которые умеют "умно" замыкать границы? Слово "умно" Вы можете интерпретировать так, как подсказывает Вам логика.

Comment: мне как-то помогло нечто такое: canny -> blur -> erode -> blur -> canny, может еще где-то там затисался dilation, точно не скажу, не найду уже

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Боюсь, что результат будет не очень. Сомнения относительно того, насколько это тупо dilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Active countours](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html) - это метод подгонки открытых или закрытых сплайнов к линиям или краям изображения 1. Он работает путем минимизации энергии, которая частично определяется изображением, а часть - формой сплайна: длиной и гладкостью. Минимизация выполняется неявно в энергии формы и явно в энергии изображения.

[Morphological Snakes](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_morphsnakes.html) -- это семейство методов сегментации изображений. Их поведение аналогично поведению активных контуров (например, геодезические активные контуры или активные контуры без краев). Однако морфологические змеи используют морфологические операторы (такие как дилатация или эрозия) над двоичным массивом вместо решения PDE по массиву с плавающей запятой, что является стандартным подходом для активных контуров. Это делает морфологических змей быстрее и численно более стабильными, чем их традиционные аналоги.